# comma separated values to single inverted quote and comma separated values

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have data as

```
    abc,defg,hijklm,op,qrs,tuv
```

I want this data to be converted to

```
    'abc','defg','hijklm','op','qrs','tuv'
```

I want to do in linux. I used "sed". I have been looking all over internet,but didnot come across a solution. Please help me.

Comment: I would use `awk`.

Comment: If your example reflects the **EXACT** structure of your input, it may be simpler to replace all `,` with `','` and then add at the beginning and the end an additional `'`.

Comment: i did this
       | sed 's/,/','/'
But it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a single quote at start (`^`) & end (`$`), and replace comma by quote-comma-quote (like you did) using sed with 3 expressions (using `-e` option to specify them):

```
echo  abc,defg,hijklm,op,qrs,tuv | sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/\$/'/" -e "s/,/',\'/g"
```

(also: protect single quotes with double quotes)

results in:

```
'abc','defg','hijklm','op','qrs','tuv'
```

in `awk` (maybe a little clumsy), generally better since field parsing is handled natively by `awk`:

```
echo  abc,defg,hijklm,op,qrs,tuv | awk -F, "{for (i=1;i<=NF-1;i++) printf(\"'%s',\",\$i); printf(\"'%s'\",\$i);}"
```

(print all fields plus comma except for the last one)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` `gsub` function. Here all the "`,`" are replaced by `','` and start and the end of the line is replaced by "`'`".

```
echo $x |awk -v q="'" '{gsub(/,/, q "&" q);gsub(/^|$/,q)}1'
'abc','defg','hijklm','op','qrs','tuv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,"\47,\47");print "\47"$0"\47"}' file

'abc','defg','hijklm','op','qrs','tuv'
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="','" -v q="'" '{$1=q $1; print $0 q}' file
```